# Can no longer select multiple words as contextual entities in Watson Assistant

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

Up until a few weeks ago (maybe Oct. 1, 2020) you were able to select multiple words in an intent example and tag them with a contextual entity through the Watson Assistant authoring tool. It could be done by holding Shift and clicking on multiple words, for example, "Scott Pilgrim."

Now, when you hold shift and click the second word, the UI freezes. The entity selection pop-up disappears, the lower edge of the word box is bold and then the entire frame goes white. Clicking each word without holding shift does not work either.

Has anyone else experienced this? I get it on Firefox and Chrome on MacOS (Mojave) and on Chrome (Windows 10).

I guess a possible workaround would be to edit the json directly (see below), but that creates other problems by changing the skill ID when you re-import.

```
    {
      "text": "I'm Scott Pilgrim",
      "mentions": [
        {
          "entity": "names_contextual",
          "location": [
            4,
            17
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
```

Comment: For me it works as designed. Do you have any browser plugins? I use it in Chrome

Comment: CORRECTION: The intended usage is just to click each word you want to group, NOT to hold Shift while you do that.

Comment: UPDATE: A workaround to this bug is to click on the first word and then DRAG the cursor across the additional words. This appears to work for me!